# What is the use of ^= and what is the opposite of it c#

Tags: c#, hex, byte

hello guys i want to know what is this symbol " ^ " use for in c#

for this simple code

```
public static Byte[] Xor = new Byte[] {0x77, 0xE8, 0x5E, 0xEC, 0xB7};
public static Byte[] data = new Byte[5];

static byte[] convertsomething(){
                Byte xors = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                data[i] ^= Xor[xors];
                xors++;
            }
                  return data;
}
```

for the c# code we have the variable data how to convert it back to the main 
values or what is the opposite of this operation data[i] ^= Xor[xors];

Comment: xor *is* the 'opposite' of xor. `(a xor b) xor b == a`

Comment: Did you try searching for "C# ^ operator"?

Comment: yes i searched but i didn't understand how it work with binary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C# the [^ operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkacc7k1.aspx) is a [boolean logical operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691309(v=vs.71).aspx), it's purpose is to perfom the [Exclusive or (XOR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) operation.

For bool operands, the result of this operation will return true only if one of the two operand is true, it mean that :

```
true ^ true // Will return false
false ^ false // Will return false
true ^ false // Will return true
```

For integral operands, it perform the bitwise exclusive OR, examples (in parenthesis are display the binary representation) :

```
1 (1) ^ 1 (1) // Will return 0 (0)
0 (0) ^ 0 (0) // Will return 0 (0)
1 (1) ^ 0 (0) // Will return 1 (1)
2 (10) ^ 1 (1) // Will return 3 (11)
15 (1111) ^ 5 (101) // Will return 10 (1010)
```

The [^= operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0zbsw2z6.aspx) will perform the same operation with the left and right operand, it mean that x ^= y is the same as x = x ^ y.

The truth table of XOR can help understand :

```
 
A    B    Result

0    0      0

0    1      1

1    0      1

1    1      0
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a binary operator, Binary ^ operators are predefined for the integral types and bool

`x ^= y`
is evaluated as `x = x ^ y`

Basically what the ^ operator allows

```
// When one operand is true and the other is false, exclusive-OR 
// returns True.
Console.WriteLine(true ^ false);
// When both operands are false, exclusive-OR returns False.
Console.WriteLine(false ^ false);
// When both operands are true, exclusive-OR returns False.
Console.WriteLine(true ^ true);
```

More information about operators @ https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0zbsw2z6.aspx & https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkacc7k1.aspx